# AWS S3 IAM policy for role for restricting few instances to connect to S3 bucket based in instance tag or instance id

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a AWS S3 already associated with all the instances for read privileges to all S3 buckets. Now I need to add a policy to the roles for write privileges(Put object) so that a few of these instances can have write permissions to certain folders in the S3. Is there any way to achieve it through instance tag(better option for me) or instance id.

I tried adding an IAM policy but when I set the condition, my instances are not getting the required privileges.

The IAM policy I used is:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1456567757624",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::testbucket/testfolder1/*",
      "Condition": {
        "ArnEquals": {
          "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:ec2:eu-west-1:<accountno>:instance/<instanceid1>"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1456567757625",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::testbucket/testfolder2/*",
      "Condition": {
        "ArnEquals": {
          "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:ec2:eu-west-1:<accountno>:instance/<instanceid2>"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Potential duplicate of: [Amazon S3 Bucket Policy: How to lock down access to only your EC2 Instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17760700/amazon-s3-bucket-policy-how-to-lock-down-access-to-only-your-ec2-instances)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an alternative, based on hints given in [Granting access to S3 resources based on role name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35711816/granting-access-to-s3-resources-based-on-role-name)...

Instead of using `aws:SourceArn`, use `aws:userid`!

The [Request Information That You Can Use for Policy Variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_variables.html#policy-vars-infotouse) documentation has a table showing various values of `aws:userid` including:

> For **Role assigned to an Amazon EC2 instance**, it is set to `role-id:ec2-instance-id`

Therefore, you could use the **Role ID** of the role that is used to launch the Amazon EC2 instance to permit access OR the **Instance ID**.

For example, this one is based on a **Role ID**:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "SID123",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:userid": [
                        "AROAIIPEUJOUGITIU5BB6*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Of course, if you are going to assign permission based on a Role ID, then you can just as easily grant permissions within the Role itself.

This one is based on an **Instance ID**:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "SID123",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:userid": [
                        "*:i-03c9a5f3fae4b630a"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The Instance ID will remain with the instance, but a new one will be assigned if a new instance is launched, even from the same Amazon Machine Image (AMI).

Comment: Thanks @John Rotenstein. The aws:userid based approach using instanceid worked like a charm. There was no proper documentation for my scenario, but with your help I was able to get this done.  Thanks a lot !!!

Answer (score 1):

The [IAM Policy Elements Reference documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements.html) says:

> `aws:SourceArn` – To check the source of the request, using the Amazon Resource Name (ARN) of the source. (This value is available for only some services.)

However, the documentation does not state *which* services can use it.

There are examples available for [its use with SQS and SNS, with a sourceARN of an Amazon S3 bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html#grant-destinations-permissions-to-s3) and also [using sourceARN with Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_AddPermission.html). However, it does not appear to be supported with Amazon EC2.