# Why does my S3 Bucket Policy work using IP but not ARN of my instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I'm debugging an *AccessDenied* error when using my EC2 Instance IDS as the Condition for a bucket policy. The following bucket policy throws an Access Denied error when I try to do a simple **PutObject**:

```
{
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::ACTUAL-BUCKET-NAME/*",
      "Condition": {
        "ArnNotEquals": {
          "aws:SourceArn": ["arn:aws:ec2:region:ACTUAL-ACCOUNT-ID:instance/ACTUAL-INSTANCE_ID"]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject", "s3:GetObjectVersion", "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:GetObjectAcl", "s3:GetObjectVersionAcl", "s3:PutObjectAcl",
        "s3:PutObjectVersionAcl", "s3:DeleteObject", "s3:DeleteObjectVersion",
        "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts", "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
        "s3:GetObjectTorrent", "s3:GetObjectVersionTorrent", "s3:RestoreObject"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::ACTUAL-BUCKET-NAME/*",
      "Condition": {
        "ArnEquals": {
          "aws:SourceArn": ["arn:aws:ec2:region:ACTUAL-ACCOUNT-ID:instance/ACTUAL-INSTANCE_ID"]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

However, If I change the Condition to be the IP of instance, I no longer get my errors and am able to **PutObject** all day.

```
{
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::ACTUAL-BUCKET-NAME/*",
      "Condition": {
        "NotIpAddress": {
          "aws:SourceIp": "ACTUAL-IP-ADDRESS"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject", "s3:GetObjectVersion", "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:GetObjectAcl", "s3:GetObjectVersionAcl", "s3:PutObjectAcl",
        "s3:PutObjectVersionAcl", "s3:DeleteObject", "s3:DeleteObjectVersion",
        "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts", "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
        "s3:GetObjectTorrent", "s3:GetObjectVersionTorrent", "s3:RestoreObject"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::ACTUAL-BUCKET-NAME/*",
      "Condition": {
        "IpAddress": {
          "aws:SourceIp": "ACTUAL-IP-ADDRESS"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The command I'm using to test with is

```
echo "hi" | aws s3 cp - s3://ACTUAL-BUCKET-NAME/ACTUAL-FILE-NAME --no-sign-request --region us-east-1
```

**What I've tried**

I've tried changing my Condition to **ArnLike** with no better results.

I've tried modifying the ARN because I'm not sure if I need to replace *region* or *accountid* with actual values or if I can leave them as 'variables' -- but again, didn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

That's generally not how you provide an EC2 server access to an S3 bucket. You would usually do that by assigning the appropriate IAM role to the EC2 server instead of using an S3 bucket policy.

If you absolutely have to accomplish this via a bucket policy, I would recommend reading the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35718371/aws-s3-iam-policy-for-role-for-restricting-few-instances-to-connect-to-s3-bucket).

Comment: I absolutely have to, sadly.